# How to close mic in google assistant app

Tags: webhooks, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I had submitted my app for review, but Google replied with "mic" issue. Google Replied :

> During our testing, we found that your app would sometimes leave the mic open for the user without any prompt. Make sure that your app always says something before leaving the mic open for the user, so that the user knows what they can say. This is particularly important when your app is first triggered.

Some Points:
1. app.ask()---leaves the mic opens.
2. app.tell()---app leaves the conversation.

**I have also enabled the "toggle" of "Set this intent as end of conversation".**

Any suggestions??

My app is one to one i.e. If user ask "my address" then address is shown, If "show me direction to PLACE_NAME" then directions are shown. BUT after it mic opens. **How to close it?**

**-----UPDATED-------**

```
fuction someName(app)
{
//---code-----

   app.ask('Alright, your address is '+ user_address);
}
```

I don't want to use app.tell() as it closes the app.
Some other suggestion for this one to one Q/A conversation.

Comment: If your app is supposed to answer only one question, then it's as you said: you need to use app.tell(). Otherwise, you can anwser any amount of question with app.ask() but you have to create an intent that will be triggered with "bye" or "exit" and will close the conversation

Comment: After you tell the user their address, if you don't want to close the app... what do you expect to happen? What do you expect the user to do? What do you expect the action to respond with? What does the conversation look like?

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing fulfillment through a webhook, then the "end conversation" toggle is ignored in favor of what you are sending from your webhook.

You don't show any code, but as noted:

- If you use `app.ask()` or one of the variants of it, the message will be sent to the user and the microphone will be left open. In this case, you should make sure it is clear what you're expecting from the user - in other words, ask a question or prompt them.
- If you use `app.tell()`, the message will be sent to the user and the microphone will be closed. This will end this conversation.

It sounds like, in your case, you should be using `app.tell()`.

Comment: Sir I have done some updates above. Please suggest if i need to improve the conversation part.